# Can I use a .NET WebView outside of a Windows Store app?

Tags: .net, webview, windows-store-apps

The old .NET WebBrowser only supports up to IE 11. It also seems that [MS will not be updating it to use Edge](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/will-the-webbrowser-control-work-with-mi/) anytime soon. If you are on Windows 10, the WebView control WILL use Edge.

I would like to develop an application that is NOT a windows store app, just a regular old Windows installer. Can I do this and use a WebView (to get Edge behavior as opposed to IE)? Or is a WebView somehow locked down to only windows store apps?

Ideally I'd like to conditionally use a WebBrowser on old versions of Windows (7), and WebView on newer (10+) with a single application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) is supported in Windows Store apps only. It will not function in a Windows desktop app.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but can Windows Store apps be distributed outside of the windows store? I.e. just have our users download an installer from our website? We don't really want to deal with yet another app store.

Comment: Yes and no. If your users have set up their systems for side-loading and trust the cert you've signed your app with then they can install it without deploying through the store. This is intended for enterprise deployment and not a general purpose install-from-a-website deployment. See https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt269549.aspx